# Nexus repository manager storage for repositories

Tags: gradle, nexus

I am new to Nexus and  recently started using nexus and wanted to do some configuration. after successful installation when I run Gradle to upload build artifacts (resultant jar file), it was uploaded successfully but why I cannot see the file at the **sonatype-work** directory. After going through some tutorials, I came to know that there should be a folder called **Storage** in sonatype-work directory but it is not there.(FYI, I am using Nexus 3.2).

Please guide me how to cofigure this **Storage** folder so that I can get those uploaded artifacts directly from the physical path and not from console.

Also please guide me how to publish a complete directory from my local system to Nexus repository manager using Gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Nexus 3.x version there's no folder called **storage**, there's a new area called *blob stores*(read the official documentation on the sonatype). You can compare screenshots:[Nexus 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6CDt.png) and [Nexus 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6xMQ.png). As you can see, nexus 2 really has this folder (**storage**, I mean), but nexus 3 has blobs instead storage.

For the uploading(publishing) your build results to the internal Nexus repository, please use `gradle-nexus-plugin`or the `maven-publish` plugins.
You can find it on the github, sorry but I can't insert more than two links in the answer :(

Comment: Thanks for responding. I already checked blobs thing but I was hoping if I can see my uploaded artifacts at some path only. blobs folder is having some .properties and .bytes files only (only details of uploaded artifacts) and not the actual file like we used to have in Nexus 2 (all the repositories and their contents), so that at times we can take backup of the repository folder.

Comment: @VinayVerma Yes, it is. For me, it was a very painful too. After "clear way" in Nexus 2 we got some not so clear as a day. I [cite](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2016/12/20/nexus-repository-3-2-enhances-support-for-backups-docker-and-firewall/): `All content written to internal storage (the ‘blob stores’) is now handled in a quasi-atomic way: files are written to a temporary location, then hard-linked to their final destination. This ensures better consistency of backups taken while Nexus is in use.`

Comment: Hey thanks! It is helpful to keep the backup of repository, but I didnt get where the actual data is saved. Anyways, can you please help me to understand how can I upload jars (dependencies) from my local system  (and are not a part of my build) to nexus repository using Gradle script (need guidance with some commands).

Comment: @vinay-verma, ok, but please give me little more context about this jar's. If they are already stored in your Nexus 2 you just can migrate them to the  Nexus 3 repo, in the other case, there's no simple way to do that. I think you should generate some code(publishing tasks) for [maven-publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#sec:the_mavenpublish_plugin) with groovy script.

Comment: I am using Nexus for the first time, till now we kept a list of jar files (dependencies) in our local system which we used at the time of building some projects. Now I though if I can upload those files to nexus and use them from there at time of building some project instead of keeping a copy of them on everyone's local system.

Comment: Are they internal artifacts, or public? In the second case, you just should create a proxy repo(it's a cache). In the first case, as I talk above you should prepare a publish tasks & execute it once.

Comment: It is the first case I am facing. I wrote some commands to publish a custom jar using publish but when the jar is getting uploaded, it is taking the name of my build jar. In short, content of uploaded jar is the same as my local one which I am publishing but its name is not the same but my built artifact. Anyways thanks for all you suggestions! let me know if you know any solution for this. :-)